# Синтаксическая ошибка в строке "print self.textarea.text()"

Tags: python

Не могу запустить программу, выводит синтаксическую ошибку

```
def runs(self):
        print self.textarea.text()
        t = TuringMachine.TuringMachine(str(self.textarea.text()))
        while not t.final():
                t.step()
            self.listWidget.addItem(t.show_tape())
        self.button.isActive = false
```

Comment: отформатируй нормально код

Answer (score 3):

Возможно у вас Python версии 3.*. В нем print является функцией, а не оператором, поэтому правильно писать `print(self.textarea.text())`.